# Why do JavaScript try/finally blocks cause function to apparently return twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, return-value

The finally block always executes last and the return statement returns control back to where the function call was made from. When used together from inside of try/finally block, the function appears to return twice instead of once, when used inside an if-else block, the finally block's return value takes effect. Is the same method call returning twice?

```
function print(value) {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
}

function testWrapped() {
    try {
        return print(true);
    } finally {
        return print(false);
    }
}

function test() {
    try {
        return true;
    } finally {
        return false;
    }
}


console.log("Result with wrapped value");
testWrapped();


console.log("Result when used inside an if statement:");
if (test()) {
    console.log("true");
} else {
    console.log("false");
}
```

the above code produces the following output:

```
Result with wrapped value
true
false
Result when used inside an if statement:
false
```

Comment: This is my explanation for this behavior,
The function evaluates the expression for return value but before returning, it executes the finally block, which is the expected behavior, as there is nothing to override the effects of finally block, the last statement returns control back to calling body. Am I on the right track? what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are *evaluated*, but only the second one is actually *returned*.

Since the evaluation of `print()` has the side-effect of outputting to the console, you can see the evaluation. But if you were to `console.log(testWrapped())` you would see the returned value after the two evaluated values.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
try {
    result1 = print(true);
    return result1;
}
finally {
    result2 = print(false);
    return result2;
}
```

Hopefully that makes it clearer what's going on.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines too, the 'print' function makes it look like it returned twice, but in reality only the return expression was evaluated and the actual value returned is the second one from the finally block (more context in the comment under the question). Thank you for clearing it up.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are using `finally` and not `catch`

Finally will execute after either try or catch.

In the conditional block, it will return the last evaluated item, `false`, and execute your else block.

see: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_try_catch.asp

> The try statement allows you to define a block of code to be tested
>   for errors while it is being executed.
>
> The catch statement allows you to define a block of code to be
>   executed, if an error occurs in the try block.
>
> The finally statement lets you execute code, after try and catch,
>   regardless of the result.

Answer (score 2):

Getting deep into it, the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-try-statement) says:

> *TryStatement* **:** `try` *Block Finally*
>
> 1. Let *B* be the result of evaluating *Block*.
> 2. Let *F* be the result of evaluating *Finally*.
> 3. If *F*.[[type]] is normal, let *F* be *B*.
> 4. If *F*.[[type]] is return, or *F*.[[type]] is throw, return Completion(*F*).
> 5. If *F*.[[value]] is not empty, return Completion(*F*).
> 6. Return Completion{[[type]]: *F*.[[type]], [[value]]: **undefined**, [[target]]: F.[[target]]}.

Applying this to your `testWrapped()` code,

1. The `try` block is evaluated. `print(true)`'s side effects happen, so `true` will be appearing in the console. The `try` block returns, so the result of evaluating it is a [Completion](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-completion-record-specification-type) with type **return** and value **whatever print(true) is: true**. *This doesn't get returned yet.*
2. The `finally` block is evaluated. Same thing: `false` in the console, Completion{[[type]]: **return**, [[value]]: **false**}.
3. *"If F.[[type]] is normal"* It's not. Next.
4. This is where the return actually happens, and it's the return from the `finally` block: false. End result: `true false` in the console, and `testWrapped()` returns false.

And the `if` statement:

1. `test`'s `try` block is evaluated: Completion{[[type]]: **return**, [[value]]: **true**}.
2. `test`'s `finally` block is evaluated: Completion{[[type]]: **return**, [[value]]: **false**}.
3. Nada.
4. `finally`'s Completion is returned: false. `test()` evaluates to `false`, and the `else` block executes.